# Is there a Jahshaka manual?

Tags: video-editor

I downloaded [Jahshaka,](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jahshakafx/) but I have no idea how to use it. Anybody know where to find a manual for it? Or even their website? I went to the SourceForge page, and clicked on the link to their website. The website never loaded.

Comment: All that jahshaka seems to have done in the last ten years or so is reorganise their website and change their logo. I'd love it to be an active project, but I'd say you'll get more out of investigating using something like blender for post: www.blender.org

Answer (score 1):

The domain: http://www.jahshaka.com/ is online and should be working. The SourceForge site has a [support page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jahshaka/support) for the software but it's currently incomplete.

Comment: It isn't up yet, but I will check back later.